# Verbs which are always followed by an object

Tags: transitivity

- They required the information to be sent as soon as possible.
- They required to sent the information as soon as possible.

I think the first one is more acceptable than second one. It seems to me that **require** needs an object after it. I don't know which verbs are always followed by an object. I also think when passive construction of such kind of verbs is used, a **to be** is compulsory, i.e **to be** will follow the object that follows such kind of verbs.

Comment: The second one is not grammatical (as you said there is no object). You could write "They required (somebody) *to send* the information as soon as possible."

Answer (score 1):

> They required the information to be sent as soon as possible.

Is correct and understandable in terms of the **urgency** of the information.  The second sentence

> They required to sent the information as soon as possible.

is grammatically incorrect, but could be changed to

> They **are** required to send the information as soon as possible.

The meaning of the two sentences are **different**, the first sentence means that the **recipient** has a requirement, the last sentence means that there is a requirement **imposed upon** the sender.